# Zxing barcode label supported printers?

Tags: java, zxing, printers

I am going to use Zxing Java API for barcode printing and our users has different types of printers so If anybody knows the supported printers for Zxing please let me know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ZXing is a barcode reader/writer library. It works with image data.

ZXing is not specific about how you accquire your image data (Camera, Scanner, Download it from the internet, paint it in a Graphic tool).

Printing of image data is also not within the scope of this library. It can help *generating* image data - but it will not tell you what to do with it. You can print it with any printer, show it on your monitor, upload it to the internet or simply store it on your hard drive.